# How to identify that user send same querystring more than once in url

Tags: asp.net

Here is my sample website page.I am giving this url(Api) to others :

```
http://localhost:someport/Test.aspx?name=pinky&SId=123&PhoneNo=XXXX
```

In this page I am accessing the query string like this

```
if (Request.QueryString["name"] != null)
{
   Name = Request.QueryString["name"].ToString();                               
}
```

Others can make request/call my page from their software.Some time they can pass same query string more than twice.Like this

```
http://localhost:someport/Test.aspx?name=pinky&SId=123&PhoneNo=XXXX&SId=43
```

In my page

```
String SId = "";
 if (Request.QueryString["SId"] != null)
    {
       SId= Request.QueryString["SId"].ToString();                               
    }

SId= "123,43";
```

If SId come like this entire my logic changes/fails.I don't want like this.If 
Same query string come more than one, should show message.

1. How to identify if query string present more than once
2. If user passes `name=pinky&rani`, my page picks up only pinky

How to handle both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Try this:

```
if (Request.QueryString["SId"] != null)
{
   var SIds = Request.QueryString["SId"].ToString().Split(',');  
   if(SIds.Count()>1)  
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('SIds come more than one!')", true);
   else 
      SId = SIds[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ali, for ur help.But I don't want like this.I want to send warning to user.

Comment: Thanks Ali for ur help.In my sample url,I have mentioned only 4 para,but there are many more para like GuId,Password.Password can be combination of both.('&,',').Will this logic fail there?Let me just check it.

Comment: So if I understand you want pick first value of every repeated duplicated parameters?

Comment: Hello Ali, if (Request.QueryString["Password"] != null)
        {
            var SIds = Request.QueryString["Password"].ToString().Split(',');

            if (SIds.Count() > 1)
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Password come more than one!')", true);
            else
                SId2 = SIds[0];
        },If I used like this for password.And if my password contain ',',logic fails.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of below code,I am able to find out ,how many time same querystring is passed

```
string productID = null;
            foreach (string productID_loopVariable in Request.QueryString.GetValues("Password"))
            {
                productID = productID_loopVariable;
                // do something with productID
            }
```